# Three.js - Alpha mask overlay texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using Three.js and I'm trying to render a texture over a mesh using an alpha mask without the transparency going all the way to the background.

I have 2 meshes, `background` and `foreground`.

The background is a texture that is green and the foreground has a texture that is RGB and transparent.

Now I want to draw a polka dot texture over that foreground but only where it is transparent. How can I do that?

I've tried using the foreground texture as an alphaMap and enabling transparency on the third, polka dot texture but it results in holes seeing through to the background where the black of the `foreground` texture used to be.

EDIT:
http://luakt.net/threejs/
Here is an example of how I'm trying to achieve this at the moment.
The end result should be the red circle visible and all the transparent areas (currently showing the green background) should be textured with `overlay.png`

I don't think using `MeshFaceMaterial` is correct but I'm not sure of another way of using 2 materials on a single mesh. I'd rather avoid the hassling of my own shaders if possible.

Comment: Are you trying to create 1 material that combines the background and foreground textures? Or do you have 2 meshes with one texture/material on each?

Comment: I have 2 meshes, `background` and `foreground`. Each have one material/texture each. Currently when I render them I have the `background` layer and on top of that I have `foreground` which displays as RGB where there are colors and white where there is transparency. I am wanting to overlay another texture onto that `foreground` but only in the transparent/white places

Comment: @2pha I've added an example of how I'm trying to do it at the moment

Comment: Creating a `ShaderMaterial` and mixing textures is [easy](http://jsfiddle.net/0e5r237x/).